# Wordpress plugin: session based form processed after shortcode generation

Tags: forms, wordpress, shortcode, php

I wrote a Wordpress plugin enabling the embedding of a form inside a post / page using a shortcode.

I use php sessions for this form.

One of the uses is to store a token, generated when the form is displayed, and then compared to the value of an hidden field of the form, also set when the form is displayed.

This way, if the submitted value of the hidden field is the same as the token's stored value in the session, I know that this is the form that was generated by my plugin and further validation takes place.

The token is generated when I create the form, when the function called by 'add_shortcode' is run. At this time its value is stored both in the session array and as the value of the form's hidden field.

The problem is that it looks like the token stored in the session is overwritten before it is compared to the hidden fields value, in other words it looks like the generation of the form (and the token) happens before the form logic (included at 'init').

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

main-plugin-file.php:

```
// Sessions
function init_sessions() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'init_sessions');

// Formlogic
add_action('init', 'include_formlogic');

function include_formlogic() 
{
    include_once 'formlogic.php'; // comparing $_SESSION['token'] and $_POST['token']
}

// Shortcode
add_shortcode('display_form', 'display_form');

function display_form()
{
    return getForm();
}
```

formlogic.php:

```
// generate unique token
function generateToken()
{
    $token = uniqid(rand(), true);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    return $token;
}

// Generate form
function getForm()
{   
    $token = generateToken();
    // Checking the form
    if (checkForm()) {
        // Get variables to be included in the form
        getVariables();
        // Start with the output buffering
        ob_start();
        include 'form-template.php';
        $output = ob_get_clean();
    } else { 
        // Alternative html in case of error
        $output = 'Error';
    }
    return $output;
}

// Comparing $_SESSION['token'] and $_POST['token'] to see if we go further:
if ($_SESSION['DRAFS_token'] === $_POST['token']) {
    // Validate the form and process it
} else {
    // Display the form along with the errors
}
```